# MySQL innodb b-tree rebalance async in background or finish on per write operation if rebalance is needed

Tags: mysql, innodb

I just curious about when mysql innodb execute rebalance operation when it is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB must update a B-tree synchronously (at the time of your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) if the index is a UNIQUE KEY or PRIMARY KEY.

Otherwise, for non-unique indexes, the changes are written to the [InnoDB change buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-change-buffer.html). These supplement the B-tree for the index.

The changes are merged into the B-tree either the next time someone's query reads those index entries, or else they are merged eventually by a "merge thread." Also InnoDB has a "slow shutdown" option which fully merges all pending change buffer entries at the time you shut down MySQL Server.

Comment: The answer is about when the change merged into btree in disk.  I also care about whether the btree in disk is always balanced or not.

Comment: To the extent that a B-tree is balanced, I believe it is. I don't have a proof of MySQL's implementation, but this is the intent of a B-tree.

Answer (score 2):

"Rebalancing" and "defragmenting" are closely related.  For this Answer, I will use the terms interchangeably.

InnoDB never automatically rebalances the *entire* BTree.

InnoDB, when storing a 'dirty' block, *may* merge that *one* block with an adjacent block, thereby doing a tiny bit of rebalancing.  Locks by other threads *may* block messing with those blocks, thereby postponing the action.

InnoDB "never" needs a full rebalancing; its BTrees are "balanced enough" for most usages.  Furthermore, the benefit from a full refragmentation is minuscule compared to the cost.  In the past, it was a full copy of the data BTree and/or index BTree.  Newer `ALTER` "algorithms" can do it `INPLACE` (or whatever).  If you insist on rebalancing, please provide before and after statistics to demonstrate how much benefit you get.

Deleting most of a table is slow and leaves the table rather fragmented.  It is usually better to copy over the rows to *keep*.  This has the effect of defragmenting "for free".  And it runs faster.  More on 'big' deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Arguably, InnoDB's BTrees are never "unbalanced" in that the depth is [I think] constant across the tree.  However, any block may become less than full.  When non-leaf nodes become less than full, that 'tilts' the BTree.  Hence, you could argue that this "fragmentation" causes "unbalance"?

The "change buffer" queues up non-`UNIQUE` index updates for 'delayed' writing.  This allows index updates to be done more efficiently, thereby somewhat benefitting any localized cleanup of the BTree.

Comment: If use AutoIncrement as primary key id, keep inserting rows into table which use cause btree to be unbalance always. So I think btree is unbalance is common case.

Comment: There are two ways to handle a tree -- top-down tends get the imbalance you envision.  Bottom-up keeps the tree more balanced.  That is, on a block split go _up_.  In the extreme, you end up making a new root node; meanwhile, the tree stays balanced.